# Polygons of Land Use Change?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, polygon, digitizing

I am doing a project where I am digitizing a map of Haiti from the 70s. Through R2V I digitized the lines and then I exported it into ArcGIS 10. I am just interested in the land use change, therefore, I have deleted the other vectors. I want all of the land use change areas to be complete polygons. I performed through data management in the toolbox a feature class to polygon operation. This was somewhat successful. However, it did not identify all polygons.

When I have complicated and nested polygons how do I get ArcGIS 10 to identify them as such?

Comment: If I understand correctly there are two polygon layers '1970' and say '2010'?